# same value in span and in input, but span will change value only when I will send the form not in real time AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a form which doesn't change variable in span but in form is the same value.

```
<b>Demo</b>
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/WXGzyp

I want to achieve a way, when variable in span will be changed **only** when I send form.

Can someone exaplain me how to achieve it???

Comment: Try [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WuVi6EwjywkZlnTPpttS?p=preview), see if that helps

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer, but what If I use ng-repeat to span and menu, look this example : https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/WXGzyp

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a deep copy so that your `ng-model` doesn't bind input form with span.

Here is an example for your updated problem with arrays:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WuVi6EwjywkZlnTPpttS?p=preview)

This is what you essentially need to do with your data, when you initialise it:

```
$scope.array2 = angular.copy($scope.array);
```